# How do I print Unity's Debug.Log to the screen/GUI?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, logging

When you run a project inside the Unity IDE itself you can see log messages in a separate console widget. However, I am developing a multiplayer game, so I need to test at least on 2+ clients, which requires standalone builds outside of the IDE, so I am not able to see log messages anymore. Is there any way to print the log on the actual screen or GUI?

Comment: I did try to look for duplicates but I honestly could not find that one

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add this `C# script` and attach it to a new game object in a scene:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ZzzLog : MonoBehaviour
{
    uint qsize = 15;  // number of messages to keep
    Queue myLogQueue = new Queue();

    void Start() {
        Debug.Log("Started up logging.");
    }

    void OnEnable() {
        Application.logMessageReceived += HandleLog;
    }

    void OnDisable() {
        Application.logMessageReceived -= HandleLog;
    }

    void HandleLog(string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type) {
        myLogQueue.Enqueue("[" + type + "] : " + logString);
        if (type == LogType.Exception)
            myLogQueue.Enqueue(stackTrace);
        while (myLogQueue.Count > qsize)
            myLogQueue.Dequeue();
    }

    void OnGUI() {
        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(Screen.width - 400, 0, 400, Screen.height));
        GUILayout.Label("\n" + string.Join("\n", myLogQueue.ToArray()));
        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
}
```

The script is adapted from [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1020051/print-debuglog-to-screen-c.html) but has been cleaned up a lot, the corner has been changed from top-left to top-right, plus a new variable for the queue size has been added so messages do not go off screen:

[image]